# Getting the Unicode Decode Error of 'cp950' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 2516: illegal multibyte sequence

Tags: python, sqlite, csv

I want to read the CSV file call testing.csv and import it into an SQLite database by using Python.

However, getting the error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJCjJ.png)

Here is the Python code:

```
import csv, sqlite3

con= sqlite3.connect('my_dataset.db')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE t(aa,bb,cc,dd);")

with open('testing.csv','r') as fin:
    dr = csv.DictReader(fin)
    to_db = [(i['aa'], i['bb'],i['cc'],i['dd']) for i in dr]

cur.executemany("INSERT INTO t(aa,bb,cc,dd) VALUES (?,?,?,?);", to_db)
con.commit()
con.close()
```

Here is the CSV file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pww9U.png)

Moreover, I also want to get the Average, Maximum and Minimum to each row. Should I use SQL keyword (AVG, MAX, MIN) or another way? Any idea? Where should I put?

Thank you~

Comment: You haven't specified an encoding for your csv file.  It's likely that the default isn't appropriate for that particular file, and you need to find out what encoding was used to create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decode your csv as `utf-8`.

To do this, change:

`with open('testing.csv','r') as fin:`

To

`with open('testing.csv','r', encoding='utf-8') as fin:`

Comment: It comes to different error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 2516: invalid start byte

Comment: I check the encoding of my  CSV file, which is                              
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='testing.csv' mode='r' encoding='cp950'>

Comment: @AlexYip You probably have non ascii characters in that csv that's preventing you from decoding, just do `errors='ignore'` so complete would be `open('testing.csv','r', encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore')`. This would mean that only the ascii characters of your csv, which is what I'm guessing you want to add to your table, will be included.

Comment: @AlexYip for the second part, yes you can use sql `AVG MAX MIN`. If you want to use something else, you can fetch the row using sql then just use python to calc the values like this: `sql="SELECT * FROM t;" row=cur.execute(sql).fetchone() average, maximum, minimum = (sum(row) / len(row), max(row), min(row))`. As for what you SHOULD use, well, try both and see what fits you the best. I really don't know your use case, maybe sql isn't even needed and you could get away with just using pandas instead. Having said that, if this answer helped you, make sure to mark it correct for future ppl to see.